# java, selenium,selenide: adding random product to the cart (stream)

Tags: selenide

i am using (java, selenium,selenide). there is a list of product div on a page. it contains product information, price and buy button. i need to randomly select 2 products that have price < 290 and click on buy button in the corresponding div. help please. it is important.

```
private final String parent = "//div[@class ='catalog-item']"; //div-ы
private final String childCost = "/div[@class='catalog-item-store']/div[@class='catalog-item-price']";//переход от div к цене

public void randomSelectionElement() {
    // ArrayList upto290 = new ArrayList<>();
    List listCardsGoods = $$x(parent);//лист дивов
    SelenideElement cost = $x(parent + childCost); //перешли к элементу Цена
    ElementsCollection costList = $$x(parent + childCost);//коллекция цен
    List sortCost = costList.stream().filter(SelenideElement -> Integer.valueOf(cost.getText().replace(" руб", "").replace(",", ".")) < 290).);
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(sortCost.size());//выбираем рандомный индекс
        sortCost.get(randomIndex);//берем элемент
        //взять xpath этой цены и перейти к его кнопке Купить
        sortCost.remove(randomIndex);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the url of the page if possible?

Comment: https://www.777555.by/kompyutery_i_seti/kompyutery_i_komplektuyuschie/materinskie_platy/?priceFrom=218&priceTo=1141&fb%5B27%5D=1

Comment: https://www.777555.by/kompyutery_i_seti/kompyutery_i_komplektuyuschie/materinskie_platy/?priceFrom=218&priceTo=1141&fb%5B27%5D=1

Comment: I didn't see any price value less than 200 on all 4 pages.

Comment: Well, of course. Choose the brand Asrock and check the checkbox In stock. and you get a list of 7 products (251,289,348,388,441,504,709).we need to click on those <290

Comment: Have you mentioned this information in your question? Always give all relevant detail in your question. Else no one will able to help you